# Is it possible to control a CAAnimation's timeline?

Tags: ios, macos, animation, core-animation, caanimation

I have a complex animation that usually runs just by itself, driven by a certain `CAMediaTimingFunction`. This works fine.

Now, I want to control that same animation's time(line) using an external value, for example from a slider or a gesture recognizer. In other words, I don't want to have the "clock" drive the timeline, but a slider, so one can scrub back and forth with it and "freeze" the animation by putting the slider to a certain value.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score -1):

It's possible (and quite easy), but I only tried this as an experiment (for a complex animation driven by a pinch gesture recognizer), so I'd love to hear if this solution is sufficient:

You need to set the speed of your animation to 0 and the time offset to the point in time you want to jump to, e.g.

```
CABasicAnimation* animation = [CABasicAnimation ...];
animation.speed = 0;
animation.duration = 1;
animation.timeOffset = 0.5;
```

will make the animation jump to the point it would be after half a second.

Now, you can't manipulate CAAnimation objects after they've been added to the layer, so you'll need to add a new animation every time the offset changes (and remove the old one, don't forget ;).